# How to paste Excel rows into Word as paragraph lines, not as a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a Word file consisting of text where each line is a link: free text with a URL behind it (Ctrl+K).  I want to sort it, but Word refuses, maybe because the lines are links.

I copied it and pasted it into an Excel sheet and sorted it.  I selected the lines, Ctrl+C to copy.

Now in an empty Word document, I want to paste it back to free text with URLs, not as a table.  If I click the Paste button (on Home tab), there are options, but they all give me a table.  None of the Paste Special choices give me the free text with URLs that I want.

Is there a way to get my list of text links sorted in a Word document, or by sorting it in Excel and bringing the text links back in?

Answer (score 0):

In the Home pane, click the *Paste* down-drop and select "Paste Special...".
From the dialog, select "Unformatted Unicode Text" (for me that's the
only option).

You will get the row not in a table format, but as text with
tab separators between the columns.

Comment: That gives me the text, but I need the hyperlink with the text, and that's gone when unformatted.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: For a link, Paste Special gives more options. The option of "Unformatted text" works for me.

Comment: But pasting Unformatted text removes the hyperlink behind the text and just pastes the text.

Answer (score 0):

1. (partial answer) There is an option hidden on the Layout tab that does not always appear, called "Data", and in that there is "Convert to Text".  I accidentally got it to appear once and it worked, but I cannot reproduce it (so far, still trying).  If anyone has a clue on how to make the Data part of Layout work, do let me know.  I suspect it's a bug that Data does not normally appear.

UPDATE: You have to have the cursor (insertion point) somewhere inside the table.  Then, a SECOND Layout tab appears at the far right.  This tab does have Convert to Text.  But if you select the entire table, you won't see it.  Convert to Text converts the entire table regardless of the location of the insertion point, so long as the insertion point is within the table.  What terrible UI design!
[image: ribbon with second Layout enabled]
2. (unsatisfactory but it works) Paste as Rich Format Text.  The text loses the hyperlink formatting (blue, underscored), and it comes in the same narrow column from Excel (which can be resized), but the hyperlinks work.  I can manually set the color to blue and set underscore and... far too much work for what I want to do.